# What is the expected cost of using LDA?

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, symmetry

Suppose that you observe $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_{100}Y_{100})$, which you assume to be i.i.d. copies of a random pair $(X,Y)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{1,2\}$.

I have that the cost of misclassification are equal, $c_1=c_2=1$.

The distributions $X|Y=1$ and $X|Y=2$ are each rotationally symmetric.

I would like to perform LDA to classify the data points.

I have that $a=S^{-1}_p(\hat{x}_1-\hat{x}_2)=(0.132-0.0732)$ and $\frac{1}{2}a^T(\hat{x}_1+\hat{x}_2)\approx 0$

And now I would like to calculate the approximate expected cost of using LDA.

So, in the textbook i'm using, the expected cost of misclassification is defined as:

> Suppose we use the classification rule $g:\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow \{1,2\}$, that assigns to group $1$ when $x \in R_1$ adnto group $2$ when $x\in R_2$. The expected cost of misclassification associated to the rule $g$ is $$\mathbb{E}[\text{cost}(Y,g(X))]=c_2\mathbb{P}(x\in R_1 | Y=2)\pi_2+c_1\mathbb{P}(x\in R_2 | Y=1)\pi_1$$
> Where $\pi_1=\mathbb{P}(Y=1|x)$ and $\pi_2=\mathbb{P}(Y=2|x)$

And so my attempt is:

$$\mathbb{E}[\text{cost}(Y,g(X))]=c_2\mathbb{P}(x\in R_1 | Y=2)\pi_2+c_1\mathbb{P}(x\in R_2 | Y=1)\pi_1=\mathbb{P}(0.132x_1-0.0732x_2\gt 0|Y=2)\pi_2+\mathbb{P}(0.0132x_1-0.0722x_2 \lt 0|Y=1)\pi_1$$

And i'm stuck here. I'm not sure how to continue from here. In particular, I don't know what $\mathbb{P}(0.0132x_1-0.0722x_2 \lt 0|Y=1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(0.132x_1-0.0732x_2\gt 0|Y=2)$ are equal to, also $\pi_1,\pi_2$.

Comment: Is the question about general $\mathbb{P}$, or about the $\mathbb{P}$ assumed by LDA (i.e., two normal distributions with equal covariance matrices)? (Without having thought more about it, I'm not sure whether even the second one is doable without much effort; the first one may be hopeless.)

Comment: @Lewian  $\mathbb{P}$ assumed by LDA

Comment: This depends on the underlying true parameters, which you don't know. In your question the estimators 0.0132 and 0.0722 are apparently assumed fixed, but then it is not clear how they are related to the underlying true parameters. In the given form the expected cost depends on these parameters and is a theoretical quantity that cannot be computed for given data without knowing the parameters (one could compute it depending on given values for them).

Comment: One could compute, at least in principle, the expected cost with training observations also random, and the decision boundary estimators also treated as random.

Comment: @Lewian So basically $\mathbb{P}(0.132x_1-0.0732x_2\gt 0|Y=2)\pi_2+\mathbb{P}(0.0132x_1-0.0722x_2 \lt 0|Y=1)\pi_1$ is the furthest I can go for computing the expected value, given the information I have?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think I have the time to figure it out. It also depends on your definition of "further". One can probably write it down in different ways and maybe see something more.